# Angular ui-router: Child not getting Parent state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular app using ui-router with the following states defined in my app.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('classes', {
    url: '/classes/:type',
    templateUrl: 'classes.html',
    controller: 'ClassesCtrl',
  })
  .state('classes.detail', {
    url: '/:id',
    views: {
        "@": {
            templateUrl: 'class.html',
            controller: 'ClassCtrl'
        }
    }
  });
```

and my controllers look like:

```
app.controller('ClassesCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams){
  $scope.foo = "bar";
});
app.controller('ClassCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams){
  console.log($scope.foo);
});
```

As you can see, class.detail hides the parent view by targeting the root level unnamed ui-view.  The issue I'm having is that the child is not inheriting the parent's scope (I can't access $scope.foo in class.detail).  It seems like the parent state gets destroyed when I go to the child state because if I click back, it has to reload all the data.

How do I effectively hide the parent view but still access the parent data?

Comment: share your data through a service

Comment: I thought a nested view automatically gets access to the parent state?  Why is it getting destroyed in my case?

Comment: The $scope that is created in the parent view should be accessible by the child view no?

Answer (score 1):

From the ui-router documentation:

> **Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only**
>
> Keep in mind that scope properties only inherit down the state chain if the views of your states are nested. Inheritance of scope properties has nothing to do with the nesting of your states and everything to do with the nesting of your views (templates).

Well, you're using `@` to define your view but your parent state is named, so you should name it `@classes`

**Edit:** I [made this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uc3h6o4/1/) to explain about names.

Comment: Ah ok thanks! How do I hide the parent view with a nested view?

Comment: in that case you would add a template *to the state*, not a view.

Comment: so you're saying I would have to use a function to determine the templateUrl as explained here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates? Essentially just something like `if (child state) child.html else parent.html`.

Comment: no, I'm saying that if you want to cover your parent's template you should set a template to the state, not the view. remember that state templates are loaded into the root ui-view. I'm on mobile right now so it's difficult to provide example code, but please, update your question with your doubts and I'll answer later